# Result by year then month php array foreach

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli, foreach

I am stuck on a php foreach loop. What I would like to do is get the results by year, then each month in that year.

```
 $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datestart, '%M') as month,
    MONTH(datestart) AS m,
    YEAR(datestart) AS year,
    holiday.Id,
    employeeId,
    datestart,
    dateEnd,
    DATE_FORMAT(holiday.dateEnd,'%D %M, %Y') AS end,
    DATE_FORMAT(holiday.datestart,'%D %M, %Y') AS startit,
    DATE_FORMAT(holiday.datestart,'%d-%m-%Y') AS st,
    DATE_FORMAT(holiday.datestart,'%d-%m-%Y') AS en,
    CONCAT(employees.empFirst,' ',employees.empLast) AS employee,
    DATE_FORMAT(holiday.datestart,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') AS start
    From holiday
    LEFT JOIN employees ON holiday.employeeId = employees.empId
    ORDER BY year asc, m, datestart
";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
$months = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $months[$row['month']][] = $row;
}

foreach($months as $months => $month) {
    echo '<b>Month &nbsp;'.$months. '</b><br>';
    foreach($month as $item){ 
        echo $item['employee']. '&nbsp;-&nbsp;'
            .$item['startit'].'&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.$item['end'].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

The result I get is month then item eg.

- January
  Item details
- March 
  Item details
- October
  Item details

What I am after is:

- 2015
- January
- Item details
- March
- Item details
- October
- Item details
- 2016
- January
- List item

I hope someone can help please. Thank you

Comment: Can you `print_r($rows);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this part of code will help You.

```
# some code

$year = $row['year']; # Important part.
$month = $row['month'];
$something[$year][$month][] = $row

# some code

foreach($something as $year => $months) { # Important part.
    # some code
    foreach($months as $month => $items) {
        # some code
        foreach($items as $item) {

# some code
```

Comment: Thanks for that but when I echo the year and month I just get ARRAY and not year and month `foreach($something as $year) { 
 echo '<b>Year &nbsp;'.$year. '</b><br>';` Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, it is array. You can always `var_dump` or `print_r`. It helps a lot. I've edited answer a little.

Comment: thank you I have learnt something tonight  `$something[$year][$month][] = $row ` is the bit that I could not work out it makes sense now .. Thank you